# Using jQuery to select the href of a link and store it as a string

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to create a program using jQuery that gets out an href from a website that looks something like this:

```
    <h2>
        <span id="Explanation"> Stuff </span>
    </h2>
    <a rel="prev" href="/1744/">Get the href from this link, as a string</a>
    <p> hey </p>
    <p> what's up </p>
```

I want to get out the href from the a element and store it as a string, and I use this code to do so:

```
    var myString = $("a[rel='prev']").attr("href");
```

But then when I look at whatever is stored in myString, it says it's undefined. Getting rid of the string and using an alert or console.log to test it gives me the same results, however, I'm pretty sure this works to get the href out of the a element. Can anyone explain why this isn't working? Thanks.

Comment: put it inside document.ready

Comment: Or include the script tag, just before the `body` closing tag. The reason being the document is not in the DOM yet, when the piece of code is executed.

Comment: Right now I'm just testing it out with the console on Google Chrome, so there is no document.ready part of my code, so I don't think that will do anything.

Comment: `$("a[rel='prev']").rel` worked for me just now in chrome.  The selector was returning markup rather than a jquery object, not sure why.

Comment: Yeah, I just got it to work too actually. Weird, I don't understand why it works now. But now that it's working I know I can use it for my nodejs webscraping thing, so thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

It works fine, it may be that you print out the variable outside of it's scope:

```js
window.onload = function () {
  var myString = $("a[rel='prev']").attr("href");
  alert (myString);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>
        <span id="Explanation"> Stuff </span>
    </h2>
    <a rel="prev" href="/1744/">Get the href from this link, as a string</a>
    <p> hey </p>
    <p> what's up </p>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<h2>
    <span id="Explanation"> Stuff </span>
</h2>
<a rel="prev" href="/1744/">Get the href from this link, as a string</a>
<p> hey </p>
<p> what's up </p>



<!--TRY THE DOCUMENT READY FUNCTION-->
<script>

    $(document).ready(function(){
        var myString = $("a[rel='prev']").attr("href");
        console.log(myString);
    })

</script>
```